# How do I handle locks in a CGI Web application?

Tags: apache, shell, cgi

I'm trying to handle the case where a long running CGI Web application is killed by closing a tab prematurely. A signal `trap` would then catch that event and clean up the [locks](https://github.com/kaihendry/Greptweet/blob/master/create.cgi#L80).

I wrote a reduced CGI which demonstrates the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2>&1
cat <<END
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html

END

trap "rm -f foo$$.log; exit" 1 2 3 6 9 14 15

while true
do
        date | tee -a foo$$.log
        echo '<br>'
        sleep 5
done
```

If I strace the CGI, I can see it gets a SIGKILL on closing on the tab, but the `trap` IIUC isn't being executed for it to clean up the log file in this instance.

It's like the CGI handler in Apache is issuing a `kill -9` which is untrappable. Any work arounds or better approaches you kind folks can suggest?